# Cleaner way of using await Promise.all to get resolved objects

Tags: javascript, async-await

Consider a bunch of promises - `result1, result2, results3` etc.

I wait to await `Promise.all` and then work with the resolved objects. No further need for the promises.

I can use a destructuring assignment like so :-

```
[result1, result2, result3] = await Promise.all([result1, result2, result3]);
```

But there is repetition there ([result1, result2...] used twice) and its ripe for mistakes with a large number of promises.

Is there a better way?

Comment: With large number you most likely wouldn't do the de-structure and would work with the full array. Using same variable names is also confusing for no reason

Comment: I'm not bothered when it's just a small number like that, but I take your point. Meaningful names rather than using positions is often useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a utility function that used an object instead of an array, something along these lines:

```
async function allKeyed(promises) {
    // Get an array of [name, value] pairs for the object's properties
    const entries = Object.entries(promises);
    // Wait for any thenables/promises in the values to settle
    const values = await Promise.all(entries.map(([_, value]) => value));
    // Build an object from those result values; this works because the
    // array from `Promise.all` is in the same order as the array of
    // values we gave it above.
    const result = Object.fromEntries(entries.map(([key], index) => {
        return [key, values[index]];
    }));
    return result;
}
```

Then it would be something like:

```
const {a, b, c} = await allKeyed({
    a: promise1,
    b: promise2,
    c: promise3,
});
```

...but with meaningful names rather than `a`, `b`, and `c`. :-)

Live Example:

```js
async function allKeyed(promises) {
    // Get an array of [name, value] pairs for the object's properties
    const entries = Object.entries(promises);
    // Wait for any thenables/promises in the values to settle
    const values = await Promise.all(entries.map(([_, value]) => value));
    // Build an object from those result values; this works because the
    // array from `Promise.all` is in the same order as the array of
    // values we gave it above.
    const result = Object.fromEntries(entries.map(([key], index) => {
        return [key, values[index]];
    }));
    return result;
}

function fetchSomething(value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`fulfilling with ${value}`);
            resolve(value);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
    });
}

(async () => {
    const {a, b, c} = await allKeyed({
        a: fetchSomething("ayy"),
        b: fetchSomething("bee"),
        c: fetchSomething("see"),
    });

    console.log({a, b, c});
})()
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

In the question you were assigning the promises to variables before `Promise.all` using the same names for both the promises (to feed into `Promise.all`) and their fulfillment values (in the destructuring), which would look like this:

```
// ...assign promises to `resultX`, then:
({result1, result2, result3} = await allKeyed({result1, result2, result3}));
```

I have them in order there, but this would work just as well:

```
// ...assign promises to `resultX`, then:
({result3, result1, result2} = await allKeyed({result1, result2, result3}));
```

Live Example:

```js
async function allKeyed(promises) {
    // Get an array of [name, value] pairs for the object's properties
    const entries = Object.entries(promises);
    // Wait for any thenables/promises in the values to settle
    const values = await Promise.all(entries.map(([_, value]) => value));
    // Build an object from those result values; this works because the
    // array from `Promise.all` is in the same order as the array of
    // values we gave it above.
    const result = Object.fromEntries(entries.map(([key], index) => {
        return [key, values[index]];
    }));
    return result;
}

function fetchSomething(value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`fulfilling with ${value}`);
            resolve(value);
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
    });
}

(async () => {
    let result1 = fetchSomething("one");
    let result2 = fetchSomething("two");
    let result3 = fetchSomething("three");
    ({result3, result1, result2} = await allKeyed({result1, result2, result3}));

    console.log({result1, result2, result3});
})()
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly this reduce chances of mistakes made caused by vars on both side of assignment not matching (and in same order)?

Comment: @Ryan - It replaces the dependency on order with a dependency on names, which seems to me to make it more robust when you get into more than a couple of them. (This is based on the premise of the question, that you want to get them individually rather than processing the result array as an array.)